# A question regarding matrix of inner product in the ordered basis from Hoffman Kunze

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

While studying Chapter - Inner Product Spaces from Hoffman Kunze, I have a question in section 8.1  .

Adding it's image:

[image]

> How can I derive the condition that the matrix must satisfy the additional condition that $X^{*}GX>0$ , X$\neq$ 0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows by definition of inner product: $(\alpha|\alpha)>0$ if $\alpha \neq 0$.